# Why does this stored procedure return an empty set?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I'm trying to build a stored proc to encapsulate some complicated logic.  Here's the basic code, anonymized a little:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

RECREATE PROCEDURE GET_DATA (
 USERID   INTEGER,
 W        INTEGER,
 X        INTEGER,
 Y        INTEGER)
RETURNS (
 ID       INTEGER,
 NAME     VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET UTF8)
AS 
BEGIN
  select first 1
    QP.ID,
    QO.NAME
  from QP
  join QO
    on QO.ID = QP.QO_ID
  where
    (QO.W = :w) and (QO.X = :x) and (QO.Y = :y)
    and ((QP.PREREQUISITE in (
      select VALUE
      from LOOKUP_TABLE1
      where USER_ID = :userid))
      or (QP.PREREQUISITE is null))
    and (QO.Q_ID not in (
      select VALUE
      from LOOKUP_TABLE2
      where USER_ID = :userid))
  order by QP.SEQUENCE desc
  into :ID, :NAME;
  suspend;
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

It's expected to return either 1 or 0 results.  It's logically correct; if I take the `SELECT` query, substitute the parameters manually, and run it in Firebird Maestro, it gives the expected result.  But if I say `select ID, NAME from GET_DATA(1, 1, 2, 3)`, with the same parameters, I get back an empty result set.

So something's going wrong at the stored procedure level.  Anyone have any idea what it is and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is `LOOKUP_TABLE2.VALUE` a nullable field? Because `<value> NOT IN (<subquery>)` can never be true if the result-set of `<subquery>` includes `NULL`. (If that's the problem, then the fix is to add `and VALUE is not null` to the subquery.)

Comment: @ruakh: No, both lookup tables have NOT NULL constraints.  Like I said, the query is logically correct; it's just not running any results when I run it as a stored proc.

Comment: @Mason Would be nice if you post DDL statemenst for these tables and some sample data so we can recreate it - SP seems to be ok

Comment: Did you try debugging it in [Hopper](http://www.upscene.com/products.hopper.index.php) or [IBExpert](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.StoredProcedure#DebugProc)?

Comment: May this be a conversion problem? Ex.: Are the columns X, Y and W of QO table defined as `INTEGER` too? Did you changed the variables to values at the SP instead of trying the select right on Firebird Maestro?

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure always returns 1 result even if the select returns 1 or 0 results because SUSPEND is independent of selection.

To obtain 0 or 1 to select the corresponding results, you can use:

```
RECREATE PROCEDURE GET_DATA (
   USERID   INTEGER,
   W        INTEGER,
   X        INTEGER,
   Y        INTEGER)
  RETURNS (
   ID       INTEGER,
   NAME     VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET UTF8)
  AS
  BEGIN
    FOR select first 1
      QP.ID,
      QO.NAME
    from QP
    join QO
      on QO.ID = QP.QO_ID
    where
      (QO.W = :w) and (QO.X = :x) and (QO.Y = :y)
      and ((QP.PREREQUISITE in (
        select VALUE
        from LOOKUP_TABLE1
        where USER_ID = :userid))
        or (QP.PREREQUISITE is null))
      and (QO.Q_ID not in (
        select VALUE
        from LOOKUP_TABLE2
        where USER_ID = :userid))
    order by QP.SEQUENCE desc
    into :ID, :NAME DO
       suspend;
  END^

  SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: either 1 or 0 **results** - nice :)

Comment: But I'm not always getting 1 result; I'm always getting an empty set (0 results) when I run this query.  Turning it into a for loop like that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating this as a selectable procedure, but Firebird doesn't see this as being selectable procedure, but as an executable procedure. If you add a `SUSPEND` at the end it will, and AFAIK that should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope.  I tried that, and it didn't work.  I'll update the question.

Comment: [This page](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/storedproc.htm) implies that the `SUSPEND` should actually be *before* the `SELECT`?

Comment: @ruakh `SUSPEND` "prints" the returns variables and before select they're empty

Comment: @ruakh No it doesn't, of you look closely the first suspend will return the value that is initialized outside of the loop.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Interesting point. I guess the author of that page was simply confused.

Answer (score 0):

`SUSPEND` is just like an inverted `FETCH` it means "send a line as result".

If you add 4 lines with SUSPEND; The result of your select * from GET_DATA(parameters) should be at least four lines with null values. Which would mean that your select statement has returned no rows, or one row with null values.

Do some tests with a simpler query.

`select 1, 'TEST' from RDB$DATABASE into :ID, :NAME;`